# Python pytype installation: Failed building wheel for pytype, Could not build wheels for pytype which use PEP 517

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pytype

I am trying to install Python static type checker Pytype on Windows 10 and am receiving this error

```
pytype/typegraph/cfg.cc(1450): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
pytype/typegraph/cfg.cc(1450): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytype
Failed to build pytype
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytype which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I installed C++ build objects, wheel and attempted the following `--no-binary`, but it didn't work.

```
pip install wheel 
py -m pip install  pytype --no-binary :all
```

Any idea how to resolve this, and install pytype?

Comment: I will try checking on my computer, I know several people are facing similar issue with Windows install

Comment: No idea if this will help but you probably want `--only-binary :all:` rather than `--no-binary :all:` - if local compilation of sources is failing, you should prefer to install the pre-compiled (binary) distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows platform is currently not supported by pytype, as described on pytype [GitHub page](https://github.com/google/pytype) under Requirements section. The only alternative is to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).